Reference management style software but for generic items
For some time I've tried to find some software that can be used as Zotero or BibDesk but for generic items,i.e. electronic units, or books, or test reports. Zotero would be perfect but the info tab is obviously made for references, so I'm missing that customization aspect there. It feels like this is a concept that should already exist but either my searching skills are bad or I'm using the wrong words when doing so.
So basically I'm looking for some software that can store or "archive" items in collections and subcollections, with notes, an info file, tags, and related items, and with the possibility of attaching documents as pdfs. very much Zotero-like. Plus points if it's collaborative, but that's not crucial; a desktop application would be enough.
